# Retrieving the number of like HTML elements from code behind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How is it possible to get the number/length of html elements with the same class names from ASP.NET code behind.

Comment: Numer/length of _which_ html file? A different or the one you are going to generate in this lifecycle? If the former, use HtmlAgilityPack, if the latter, i have no idea since it is not predictable what ASP.NET will render on the client's browser.

Comment: aspx file associated or corresponding to the code behind file.

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<Control> FindRecursive( Control c, Func<Control,bool> predicate )
{
    if( predicate( c ) )
        yield return c;

    foreach( var child in c.Controls )
    {
        if( predicate( c ) )
            yield return c;
    }

    foreach( var child in c.Controls )
        foreach( var match in FindRecursive( c, predicate ) )
           yield return match;
}
```

//Use this forloop get controls

```
foreach( WebControl c in FindRecursive( Page, c => (c is WebControl) && 
                           ((WebControl)c).CssClass == "test" ) )
{
    //Code
}
```

<kbd>[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766408/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-instead-of-id-in-asp-net)</kbd>

Comment: OP wants to analyze the  html elements not the server controls (or at least not only).

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to analyze the HTML which is rendered by ASP.NET since that  depends on factors like the browser of the client.

However, you can try following approach which uses [`control.RenderControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx) to render the HTML and [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to analyze it:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string thisHtml = RenderControl(this.Form);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(thisHtml);
    var nodeColl = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'fooClass')]");
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + nodeColl.Count);

    // here a linq approach with the same result:
    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
        .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value=="fooClass");
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + nodes.Count());
}

private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    control.RenderControl(writer);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I have used a simple test page with some some controls where some of them have a class/CssClass = `fooClass`. The result seemed to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get html elements that marked as runat="server" from server side. Just a suggestion: get the html elements that have same class from client side via jquery selectors and pass them to the server via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override Render method:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
     base.Render(htw);
     string s = sb.ToString();

     //here you are able to use HTMLAgilityPack to parse HTML

     writer.Write(s);
 }
```

You will retrieve HTML as string s and will be able to parse it